# Can we use Airbnb Cereal font within android app for free?

Tags: mobile-application, font, android

I'm newbie on ux stackexchange community so , pardon me if it's wrong place to ask my question .

Currently I'm developing an Android application & I really like UI/UX of Airbnb so , I'm trying to create similar kind of User Interface for my application.

One main thing I came across was their own **Airbnb Cereal** fonts & I really like them but not sure whether I can use it within my application . So , anyone has idea on it ?

Comment: I have no idea about the license, but you can certainly find out on the Airbnb site (if it's "their" font, they will tell you if you are allowed to use it) or on the site of the font foundry that created it. A brief search brought up some comments saying that there's no download options anywhere - so I assume they want to keep it "theirs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airbnb Cereal is Airbnb's bespoke typeface (i.e. a typeface custom designed for the company to serve their needs) and can be used only by Airbnb and their partners in some way. So legally you are not allowed to use the font in your application.